# How do I progress in the "Mori Mountain Estate" mod?

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

Before I say anything, here is a link to the mod that I am referencing: http://planetelderscrolls.gamespy.com/View.php?view=mods.detail&id=275

So, there's this mod called "Mori Mountain Estate". It is, in essence, a HUGE housing mod in Balmora. It has a self organizing/selfstacking library, lots of secrets hidden throughout, and, a HUGE dungeon with strange things underneath it.

Firstly, you need to be like level 50 and a Master of Alchemy to even hope to crack it's depths effectively. It's full of OP equipment, and absurdly powerful monsters both unique and familiar, many of them stronger and more numerous than anything in the main game.

Each 'boss' unique monster drops a key, or at least most do. The final one as far as I can tell is a Spriggan looking witch thing that does an unholy shit ton of fire damage, and an extremely cryptic and creepy unique book (from the mod) referencing the fate of the one who made the estate. The book is found near her 'cage'.

There is a sarcophagus, you will notice, before the dungeon even begins, and 'seals' that I ASSUME have something to do with the keys somehow, but I can't figure any of it out. The dungeon ends HELLA abruptly, and I feel like there is something I am MISSING. Something else that can be done that references the (5, I think. The number of unique bosses on the mod) seals outside the sarcophagus.

There are tons of books that the man, "Zureel", in the nearby tavern in Balmora who sells you the house also sells, that have lots of lore from Hammerfell and on the house in particular. I have tried contacting the maker of the mod, but to no avail. I have no idea what is farther on in the 'questline' of this mod.

I don't care how you do it. Through hacks, cheats, looking at code like some of you smarty pantses know how.

I really gotta know what I'm supposed to do/what else is in the mod. I've had the idea that perhaps one could look at characters/models/references that the mod creates in the actual mod files. Find the ones that aren't Zureel/any of the bosses/find any triggers or dialogues associated with them, equipment drops/etc.... but I don't know how to do that shit, though. I dunno.

You guys figure it out. :)

I just REALLY wanna know. It's been eating at me for like a year.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://mw.modhistory.com/download-35-7306), there is no "questline" of any sort included in this mod.

As for the dungeon :

> SECRET CRYPT is just a **regular hack and slash** with several bosses that drop interesting (balanced) items (I'm a purist). The crypt is intended for level 20+ characters but it can be done at lower level if you're careful.

The two NPC, Zippy and Nami, are interesting though.

> **Zippy** the *ingredient sorting* mouse, just click and zoom all the ingredients in your inventory are sorted into the jars.
>
> **Nami** the Librarian will *auto-sort all the books in your inventory*. Just talk to her like you would Zippy and in the blink of an eye she makes duplicates of your books, places the copies on the shelves in a nice orderly fashion and places all the originals into one of three alphabetized closets.

Comment: This question is quite old. Is it bad to answer it anyway ?

Comment: Wow, I'm just seeing this now. I appreciate the time you put into your answer! I'm a little frustrated by it though. The reason I asked, was because the objects preceding the crypt are interactive, and there's the same number of keys as 'seals' it looks like. The object they appear to be sealing is a container, but nothing I do with any of the keys or objects seem to have any function. It may be that the person just never finished that aspect or decided not to develop it, but by god is it frustrating! haha.